# CORS in VisualStudio (Angular app)

Tags: cors, web-config

Been pulling my hair out on this for hours. I'm learning Angular and trying to write an app that uses an API in a home automation server (Indigo). Whenever I try to call one of the RESTAPi's I get this:

```
    HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: index.html
Main Controller Startup...
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://192.168.168.157:8176/devices// required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
File: index.html
SEC7120: Origin http://localhost:50441 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
File: index.html
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

File: index.html
Error: ; 0
```

.

```
http://192.168.168.157:8176/devices/ is the server (on a Mac on my local network)
http://localhost:50441 is the web server that Visual Studio uses during debugging
```

I've added  to my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

has anybody got any idea what I need to do to get this to work?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Do you see the header in the dev tools? What server are you running?

Comment: @mpm thanks for reply. Which header should I be looking for? I guess it's IIS, as the its a server that visual studio uses for debugging. The API is connecting to a 3rd party app. but I think my problem is in the web server where my angualar app is running

Comment: These are the headers for request to API: Request URL:http://172.30.90.30:8176/devices
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Origin:http://localhost:50376
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:50376/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0):

So, I got it working.

Turned out it was nothing to do with the local asp.net server. The server I was trying to connect to is written in CherrPy. All I had to do was add

```
cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
```

Obviously, I'll restrict it further once I finish testing.

Regards

Mark